# RxJava - how to repeat two observable's depending on second response

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I have to two API calls.

I want to call 1 after the response call 2
if 2 `result` is `notValid` retry the full sequence again up to 3 times.

Any suggestions how to do this?

I'm using `retrofit`and both requests are `Observable's`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `Observable`s return a single object (in which case `Single` would be preferrable instead), flatMap the result of the first onto the second, then conditionally fail the second with an error to have a [retry](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#retry-long-io.reactivex.functions.Predicate-) detect it and do its job:

```java
static final class RetryRequestedException extends Exception { }

// no need for more than one of this
static final RetryRequestedException RETRY_INDICATOR = new RetryRequestedException();

source1.flatMap(value1 -> 
    source2.flatMap(value2 -> {
       if (value2.notValid) {
          return Observable.error(RETRY_INDICATOR);
       }
       return Observable.just(value2);
    })
)
.retry(3, error -> error == RETRY_INDICATOR)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `switchMap` for that, so it will be something like:

```
final PublishSubject<Object> retry = PublishSubject.create()

final Observable<YourObject> twoResponses = retry
    .startWith(new Object())
    .switchMap {
        service.call1()
            .switchMap { response1 -> 
                service.call2()
                    .map { response2 -> /* combine response1 and response2 to YourObject*/}
        }
    }
    .subscribeOn(networkScheduler)
    .observeOn(uiScheduler)
    .replay(1).refCount()

twoResponses.filter { /* need to retry */ }
    .map { new Object() }
    .subscribe(retry)  //don't forget to unsubscribe when activity close
```

Comment: Can you please give an explanation?

Comment: what exactly is not clear, some specific part of code, or the whole algorithm?